# R Coloring Edges in diagonalNetwork()

Tags: r, graph-coloring, networkd3

I am exploring the features of networkD3, `diagonalNetwork` function.

Below is the toy example

```
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0(
        "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
        "master/JSONdata//flare.json")

Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

Flare$children = Flare$children[1:3]

diagonalNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9)
```

I am wondering if there is any option to color just the edges under the node **cluster**. This is not important but just trying to aim for perfection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but if you know the indices of the links you want to color, you can inject some JavaScript into the linkColour argument like this...

```
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
  "master/JSONdata//flare.json")

Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

Flare$children = Flare$children[1:3]

linkColourJS <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return i > 24 && i < 29 ? "red" : "#ccc"; }'))

diagonalNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9, linkColour = linkColourJS)
```